# Is there a naming convention for constants in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am writing a simulator for a spiking neural network. There are tons of constants, time constants, voltage levels, etc.

Sometimes when I'm looking at my code and see a constant name, I look around the function to see where it's defined not realizing that it's one of the constants (until a few seconds later) .. I love Haskell and programming in it is super comfortable except for this. In Scheme, I think there was a convention of starting constant names with an "*".

I've looked at several coding convention sites and couldn't find anything.

Is there a Haskell convention for this or should I just invent my own, such as the first letter being "k" .. kTauOne, kSpikeRateMax ..

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no such convention and there shouldn't be. After all, in some sense *all* variables are constants in Haskell (within the right scope), as are all functions, and even those constants that would actually correspond to global constants in an imperative language can serve very different purposes.

That said, you can absolutely organise your constants / variables / whatever with whatever prefix you wish, but don't hard-link it to the name. Instead, put the constants in a module and import it qualified!

```
module MyKoolKonstantz where

τOne :: Double
spikeRateMax :: Double
...

module TehPrograhmStufz where

import qualified MyKoolKonstantz as K

simThoseSpikes :: Foo
simThoseSpikes = quinum (K.spikeRateMax)
```

Often, actually using global constants isn't a good idea anyway: they may be constant right now, but perhaps soon you need two different kinds of simulations with different constants?

That's where it makes sense to put them into a *configuration type* and pass that an argument.

```
data SpikeNNConf = SpikeNNConf
  { τOne, spikeRateMax, ... :: Double }

simThoseSpikes :: SpikeNNConf -> Foo
simThoseSpikes cfg = quinum (spikeRateMax cfg)
```

Here the `cfg` also kind of acts as a marker for "that's a constant".

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestions and options! I can see that for big projects the 'record' type would be good for maintainability but it does make the code a bit more verbose. The 'module' approach is great for medium projects where, as you say makes 'configuration' more flexible. For small projects though the leading letter approach seems Ok .. So, now I have a mix of project sizes and now have various
more arrows in my quiver!

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to think of constants (=values exported from a library with non-function types) and coming up pretty shy on examples. `pi` is about the only really pure constant that comes to mind. There's zero-field constructors all over the place (`False`, `Nothing`, `LT`, `()`, `[]`), recognizable by their leading capital letter with just a few exceptions; and there's algebraically-relevant constants in some classes (`mempty`, `zero`, `empty`, `one`) and common APIs (`empty` from various container libraries). Arguably the base-case pretty-printers from various pretty-printer libraries qualify, e.g. `emptyDoc`, `line`, `softline`, `hardline`, `colon`, `lparen`, `space` from [prettyprinter](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/prettyprinter-1.7.1/docs/Prettyprinter.html#g:11).

Among these examples, there doesn't seem to be a particularly strong convention. I say make up a convention that seems sensible to you and run with it.

Comment: Daniel .. Thanks for the help! I'm now more comfortable using
the 'k' approach for small projects without 'coding-standard-guilt' :-)

Answer (score 2):

If your constants have a sensible notion of equality (unlike, say, `pi @Double`) then you can define them using bidirectional pattern synonyms. This isn’t very common, but it’s a good middle ground between a normal constant and a `data` or `newtype` definition.

```
{-# Language OverloadedStrings, PatternSynonyms #-}

import Data.Text (Text)
import Data.Text qualified as Text

pattern FieldSeparator :: Char
pattern FieldSeparator = '-'

pattern LayerPrefix :: Text
pattern LayerPrefix = "layer-"
```

If you defined the constant `fieldSeparator = '-'`, you might use it with a Boolean guard:

```
nextField (c : _) | c == fieldSeparator = Nothing
```

Whereas, you can use the bidirectional pattern `FieldSeparator` in both patterns and expressions.

```
nextField (FieldSeparator : _) = Nothing
```

```
Text.intercalate
  (Text.singleton FieldSeparator)
  ["turnip", "parsnip", "rutabaga"]
```

You can also combine these into larger bidirectional patterns.

```
{-# Language ViewPatterns #-}

pattern Layer :: Text -> Text
pattern Layer suffix <- (Text.stripPrefix LayerPrefix -> Just suffix)
  where
    Layer suffix = LayerPrefix <> suffix
```

```
case "layer-five" of
  Layer layer -> Right ("layer: " <> layer)
  other -> Left ("not a layer: " <> other)
```

Another guideline: if you feel the need to use the `{-# Complete #-}` pragma to tell the compiler that pattern-matching on some set of constants is exhaustive, at that point, it’s almost certainly easier to make a `data` type.

Comment: +1 but it really isn't tenable to see this as an uppercase->constant convention. As you say yourself (with `pi`), many constants can't reasonably be expressed as constructors, and vice versa constructors are often used in a very different manner from the constant the OP is asking about.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Agreed, it’s a nice technique that can be put to similar uses, so I thought it was worth mentioning. But I think the heart of it is that Haskell just doesn’t need to treat constants specially. Other features fill those needs, and everything’s constant anyhow.

Comment: Jon, thanks for the new (to me) idea! Haskell is a very rich language and this greatly improves the 'granularity' of possible solutions for my constants ...